# toggle MatSlideToggle in Angular 8 component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular8

I keep getting this error:

"ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of undefined"

Here is my code **test.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSlideToggle } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('testSlider', { static: false }) t: MatSlideToggle;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.t.checked = true;
  }

}
```

And **test.component.html**

```
<mat-slide-toggle #testSlider>Test</mat-slide-toggle>
```

What am I doing wrong? This seems simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `@ViewChild` is not defined if you try to access it on `ngOnInit`. Try this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSlideToggle } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('testSlider', { static: false }) t: MatSlideToggle;

  constructor(private changeDetectorRef:ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.t.checked = true;
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }

}
```

Comment: Now I get this error "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked." - Although it is checked.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a reference of the MatSlideToggle in your component you can directly use the Input-Property of the MatSlideToggle-Directive
(https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/api).

**test.component.html**

```
<mat-slide-toggle [checked]="toggleChecked">Test</mat-slide-toggle>
```

**test.component.ts**

```
export class TestComponent { 
  toggleChecked = true;
}
```